# Cannot subtract value from VBA property

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following code, I am trying to subtract `.5` from the `text53` object if the date value is higher than 15, but I keep getting the error `"Invalid Use of property"` error

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    Dim Maxdate As Integer, LValue As Integer, LValue2 As Integer
    Dim Mvalue As Integer, Dvalue As Date, RateVal As Integer

    LValue2 = 0.5
    RateVal = Me.Text31.Value * Me.Text27.Value
    Dvalue = Me.Text43
    Mvalue = DateDiff("m", Me.Text41, Me.Text43)

    If Format(Dvalue, "DD") >= 15 Then Me.Text53 - LValue2

    Me.Text53 = Mvalue
    Me.Text51 = Me.Text53 * RateVal
End Sub
```

Comment: What line does it error on?

Comment: `   If Format(Dvalue, "DD") >= 15 Then Me.Text53 -LValue2 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()

Dim Maxdate As Integer
Dim LValue As Integer  
Dim LValue2 As Single
Dim Mvalue As Integer
Dim Dvalue As Date
Dim RateVal As Integer

LValue2 = 0.5
RateVal = Me.Text31.Value * Me.Text27.Value
Dvalue = Me.Text43
Mvalue = DateDiff("m", Me.Text41, Me.Text43)
Me.Text53 = Mvalue

If Format(Dvalue, "DD") >= 15 Then 
  Me.Text53 = Me.Text53 - LValue2
End If
Me.Text51 = Me.Text53 * RateVal

End Sub
```

I think your main problem is this:  Me.Text53 - LValue2

You need to assign that value to something.  By itself it will only produce errors.  Changing that line to **Me.Text53 = Me.Text53 - LValue2** or **Me.Text53 = Mvalue - LValue2** would fit the bill.

Other things of note: you can't assign a decimal to an integer datatype, it'll round it to a whole number.  Also, assigning Mvalue to Text53 needs to happen before your conditional subtraction of 0.5 or that part will just get overwritten.

Comment: This works. just need and IF after End on the third to last line.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks.  I've been working in MS SQL a lot and they have that difference.